# Pty doesn't get closed, althoguh close() syscall is called

Tags: linux, go, terminal, linux-kernel, pty

I'm implementing features of an ssh server, so given a shell request I open a pty-tty pair.
A snippet:

```
import (
    "github.com/creack/pty"
    ...
)

func attachPty(channel ssh.Channel, shell *exec.Cmd) {
    mypty, err := pty.Start(shell)
    go func() {
        io.Copy(channel, mypty) // (1) ; could also be substituted with read() syscall, same problem
    }
    go func() {
        io.Copy(mypty, channel) // (2) - this returns on channel exit with eof, so let's close mypty
        if err := syscall.Close(int(mypty.Fd())); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error closing fd") // no error is printed out, /proc/fd shows it's successfuly closed
        }
    }
}
```

Once the ssh channel gets closed, I close the pty. My expected behavior is that it should send SIGHUP to the shell.

**If I comment out the `(1)` copy (src: mypty, dst: channel), it works!**
However - when it's not commented out:

- The `(1)` copy doesn't return, meaning the `read` syscall from `mypty` is still blocking, and doesn't return eof => master device doesn't get closed?
- shell doesn't get SIGHUP

I'm not sure why if I comment out the `(1)` copy it works, maybe the kernel reference counts the reads?

My leads:

- pty.read is actually dispatched to the tty, as said in:
  [pty master missing read function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529914/pty-master-missing-read-function)
- [Walkthrough of SIGHUP flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012153/who-is-the-original-sender-of-sighup-when-the-ssh-connection-is-closed)
- `pty_close` in `drivers/tty/pty.c`, which calls `tty_vhangup(tty->link);`, see [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/pty.c#L79)
- Linux Device Drivers, 3rd edition, PTY chapter

Go notes:

- I close the fd directly, because otherwise using the usual `os.File.close()` doesn't actually close the fd for some reason, it stays open in `/proc/<pid>/fd`
- substituting the `(1)` copy with a direct `read` syscall would lead to the same outcome

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself and spent some time investigating.

Turns out that this is deliberate behaviour of Go runtime. Specifically it prevents files from being closed [while they are being read by another goroutine](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21834#issuecomment-329263641). This was introduced to [mitigate a race condition](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7970) where a goroutine may read from a wrong file if the file descriptor was closed and reused by another goroutine.

I don't have a good solution for the SSHD use case. I may update this answer later. Have you come up with some workaround yourself?